# Is there any built in class with HTTP response codes and its categories?

Tags: java, http-response-codes

When I need to check if a response code is one of success codes (2xx), then I usually create a integer array and look thru it. For example,

```
public static final int[] SUCCESS_STATUS_CODES = new int[]{
        200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 226
};
```

I do the same for other response codes.

I was wondering if there is a built-in object which already holds all these codes and regularly updates them which I can use?

For example,

```
//pseudo code
if(responseCode is from success 2xx category)
   do something
else if (responseCode is from error 4xx category
   do something
```

Comment: What HTTP client do you use?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730283/does-java-have-a-complete-enum-for-http-response-codes

Comment: I use `HttpURLConnection`. Android development.

Comment: @RichardNeish Your link pretty much answers my question, but says nothing about categories. Check my pseudo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such class in the standard library.  The closest I know if is `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, which provides static constants for the various codes.

But you seem to be going to more work than you need to do. HTTP response code categories are built into their values.  You should be able to do something along these lines:

```
switch (responseCode / 100) {
    case 1:
        /* informational response */
        break;
    case 2:
        /* success response */
        break;
    case 3:
        /* redirection response */
        break;
    case 4:
        /* client error response */
        break;
    case 5:
        /* server error response */
        break;
    default:
        /* bad response code */
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`org.springframework.http.HttpStatus` has a method `HttpStatus.is2xxSuccessful()` returns a boolean. It's part of Spring, not built into Java, but hopefully will still be useful to some people.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the part but I would like to extend Jaxon's message:

```
    int responseCode = 200;
    HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.valueOf(responseCode);
    if (httpStatus.is2xxSuccessful())
    {
      // do something
    }
```